# How to enforce strict typing when setting a variable?

Tags: typescript, types, casting, coercion

I would like to ensure that the data I read from a YAML file is aligned with the type of the variable it goes into:

```
type Http = {
  name: string
  api: string
  resp: number
  status: string
  statusEffective: string
}

export const monitorHttp = () => {
  const conf = getConf("conf-http.yml") as Http[]
  log.info("", conf)
}
```

`getConf` is defined as

```
export const getConf = (file: string) => {
  try {
    return yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(`../data/${file}`, "utf8"))
  } catch {
    log.error("cannot load config.yaml, aborting")
    process.exit(1)
  }
}
```

What is therefore returned by `getConf` is of type `any` there will be various structures for different `.yml` files).

I was expecting that by coercing `conf` to be `Http[]` only data with this structure would be accepted.

It is not true however, by sending fields that do not exist in `Http` the program still runs fine. With a YAML file containing

```yaml
- name: jellyfin
  api: http://jellyfin.xxxx
  resp: 200
  status: enabled
  wazaa: wazii
```

I get the result

```
2023-02-26 17:55:49.979 INFO    \W\dev-perso\hass-monitoring\src\monitor-http.ts:14         [
  {
    name: 'jellyfin',
    api: 'http://jellyfin.xxxx',
    resp: 200,
    status: 'enabled',
    wazaa: 'wazii'
  }
]
```

Why does the program run fine despite `wazaa` not existing in `Http`? Or, more specifically: **how to enforce a strict type checking when initializing or updating a variable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the zod library for runtime validation.

You'll need to define a schema in a slightly different language than Typescript, and then you'll automatically get a Typescript type and a function for parsing an arbitrary value against this schema.

Answer (score 1):

Without a schema, `yaml.load` cannot know what it is expected to read, so it will parse and return anything that is valid yaml. Type coercion in TS doesn't validate anything, instead it just communicates to the compiler that **you** know what the type is.

More to the point, if you want to ensure that your input has a given structure and type, you either need to validate the data yourself or use a library that does that for you.

Comment: *Type coercion it TS doesn't validate anything* - this is what I was missing, I thought that there would be an analysis of the content of the variable vs the announced type.